# An API for calculating a road distance

Tags: android, google-api, distance

we develop a application that we need calculate road distance with two Geographical spots (lat & long) like google API and i cant use google API. please help us..thanks

Comment: Lack of research

Answer (score 0):

**You can calculate distance in kilometers by using following code:**

```
private double deg2rad(double deg)
{
    return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
}

private double rad2deg(double rad)
{
    return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
}  

double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2)
{
    double theta = lon1 - lon2;

    double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) 
                    * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2))
                    + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1))
                    * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2))
                    * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));

    dist = Math.acos(dist);
    dist = rad2deg(dist);
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;

    return (dist);
}
```